# Share Extension don't open/share .HEIC type image

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

i created share extension for my app which can share image/videos from photos(Gallery) and it work properly but here problem is if i select `.HEIC` type file then click on my share extension  it show error as shown in below screenshot .

[image]

```
import UIKit
import Social
import MobileCoreServices
import AVKit
import Toast_Swift

//@objc(ShareExtensionViewController)
class ShareViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var blurview: UIVisualEffectView!
    
    var allMedia = [Data()]
    var singleImage = UIImage()
    var imagesUrl = [URL]()
    let groupPath = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "
my group identifire ")
    var saveDone = Bool()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let attachments = (self.extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem)?.attachments ?? []

        self.btn.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
        self.btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.cancel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.image.clipsToBounds = false
        applyshadow(image: image)
        blurview.isHidden = true
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.handleSharedFile()
    }
    
//    MARK:- function
    
    func applyshadow(image: UIImageView) {
        image.clipsToBounds = false
        image.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.systemGray.cgColor
        image.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        image.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        image.layer.shadowRadius = 7.5
    }
    
    func videotext(string : String) ->Bool{
        let videoextension = [".MP4",".mp4",".mkv",".MKV",".AVI",".avi",".mov", ".MOV"]
        if videoextension.contains(string){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    
    func videoThumb(filepath: URL) -> UIImage{
        do{
//            let filepath = data?.appendingPathComponent(lbl[indexPath.row])
            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: filepath, options: nil)
            let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1), actualTime: nil)
            let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            return uiImage
        }catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return UIImage()
        }
    }
    
    private func handleSharedFile() {
        // extracting the path to the URL that is being shared
        let attachments = (self.extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem)?.attachments ?? []
        let contentType = kUTTypeData as String
        for provider in attachments {
            // Check if the content type is the same as we expected
            if provider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentType) {
                provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentType,
                                  options: nil) { [unowned self] (data, error) in
                    guard error == nil else { return }
                    if let url = data as? URL {
                        imagesUrl.append(url)
                        print(imagesUrl)
                        if videotext(string: String(url.lastPathComponent.suffix(4))){
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.image.image = videoThumb(filepath: url)
                                if attachments.count > 1 {
                                    lbl.text = "\(attachments.count) Items"
                                }else{
                                    lbl.text = url.lastPathComponent
                                }
                            }
                        }else {
                            let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                if provider == attachments.last{
                                    self.image.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                                }
                                self.singleImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
                                if attachments.count > 1 {
                                    lbl.text = "\(attachments.count) Items"
                                }else{
                                    lbl.text = url.lastPathComponent
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }else {
                        print("Impossible to save image")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

thank You in advance for read, giving attention, answer and upvote my question :)

Comment: Looks like a problem with the photos app, not with your share extension. Did you try restarting your device?

Comment: yes i restart device , reinstall app even i also restart my system too but same problem

Comment: Are other extensions working fine with this image ? For ex:native application share extension (mail,notes)

Comment: Why not simply `url.pathExtension`? instead of `url.lastPathComponent.suffix(4)`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but can you also focus on my question ...!

Comment: I have the same problem with my extension. I am using the IMG_0006.HEIC file that is in the iPhone 11 photo gallery by default (simulator, after fresh install). Presumably this happens before calling the extension. My guess is that iOS tries to convert the file instead of sending its URL to the extension. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Any news on that?

Comment: no i don't get any answer yet