# Does iOS Share extension open .heic images? NSExtensionActivationRule for .heic

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension, heic

This question [already has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65033054/share-extension-dont-open-share-heic-type-image), so I'm actually stack on too and wonder, if there any solution.

I have an app extension, that opens `pdf` and `images`, BUT not open `.heic` files from Simulator. I can't build it for device for any reason now.

```
<key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <string>
    SUBQUERY (
      extensionItems,
      $extensionItem,
      SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf" OR
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.file-url" OR
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url" OR
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
      ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count AND $extensionItem.attachments.@count &lt;= 10
    ).@count == 1
  </string>
```

I was trying use `public.heic`, `public.heif-standard` according to [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttypeheic), but still no luck.
[image]